# jquery ajax handling dynamically created buttons

Tags: jquery, ajax, button

In my jsp page I am creating buttons inside `for-each` loop. I want to submit these buttons simultaneously and process response with ajax request (same request with different parameters). I am using `jquery 1.10`. Could anyone provide me sample code to handle this scenario. Here is the code. I started writing the code and did not know how to write the code to figure out" when response comes from server , for which request it is correlated to.

I have implemented auto complete recently. So I started from that point to understand and implement ajax on button click

Below is the JSP part

```
<c:forEach var="label" items="${sessionScope.labels}">
    <input type="submit" name="submitLabelBtn" value="Submit Label" id="${label.labelName}" class="button exitSubmitButton" />
</c:forEach>
```

Javascript below

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("submitLabelBtn").click(function(e) {
            var = this.id;
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "FrontController",
                data: {
                    id: val
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    if (!data.length) {
                        var result = [{
                            label: 'No matches found',
                            value: response.term
                        }];
                        response(result);
                        ele.style.display = "none";
                        $("#loading").hide();

                    } else {
                        response(data);
                        ele.style.display = "none";
                        $("#loading").hide();

                    }

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post what you have written so far?

Comment: I have posted my code above

Comment: where is the loop and where are your creating your buttons?

Comment: The jsp part contains the loop

Comment: oh ok. since your buttons are dynamic, you can do `$('.button').on('click', function(){ // your code here });` where `.button` is the css class of the button.

Comment: did it work for you @RajaVivekanandhan?

Comment: hi Sushil, I am yet to try , but I have a question. How does the javascript knows which of the button click event to notify since the user can click on multiple buttons at the same time. Isn't that at the some part of code , we need to check for which id we received response and update that button with success message ? I will implement your suggestion tomorrow.

Comment: how do you know for which id you're receiving the response? since you have a unique id for every button, you can just get the id in the click event and this way you'll be able to know which button was clicked

Comment: I am not taking this approach since my UI design changed

Comment: so what approach are you using now?

Comment: Submitting form for each button click :(. I am working on a very old code. Implementing ajax requires lot of modification on the existing code . I cannot do that as it is a risk and requires more time of qa.